# Power of 10 problems

Tags: java

I am running in stupid problem, have never seen it before.

I am trying to do a very simple task for some mathematical calculation that requires growing power of 10.

To start with I wrote a very simple growing loop that works fine, but what I do not understanding, the higher value get, the not precise results get.

I would like to know why this happen? and how to fix it?

**My test code:**

```
public class PowerOfTen {

    private int lineCounter = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PowerOfTen powerOfTen = new PowerOfTen();

        powerOfTen.growingOfTenMethodOne();
        powerOfTen.growingOfTenMethodTwo();
    }

    public void growingOfTenMethodOne() {

        double MAX_VALUE = 1e50;
        lineCounter = 1;

        for (double i = 1; i < MAX_VALUE; i = i * 10) {
            System.out.printf("%03d%1s%f\n", lineCounter, " | ", i);
            lineCounter++;
        }
    }

    public void growingOfTenMethodTwo() {

        double MAX_VALUE = 50;
        lineCounter = 1;

        for (double i = 0; i < MAX_VALUE; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%03d%1s%f\n", lineCounter, " | ", Math.pow(10, i));
            lineCounter++;
        }
    }

}
```

Both methods works and suppose to return correct results, but on both of them give some not accurate results as you can see in examples below.

**Method 1:**
line 24, 26, 27, 28, 31, 32, 33 etc is not returning correct results

```
022 | 1000000000000000000000.000000
023 | 10000000000000000000000.000000
024 | 99999999999999990000000.000000
025 | 1000000000000000000000000.000000
026 | 9999999999999999000000000.000000
027 | 99999999999999990000000000.000000
028 | 999999999999999900000000000.000000
029 | 10000000000000000000000000000.000000
030 | 100000000000000000000000000000.000000
031 | 999999999999999900000000000000.000000
032 | 9999999999999999000000000000000.000000
033 | 99999999999999990000000000000000.000000
```

**Method 2:**
line 24, 30 is not returning correct results

```
022 | 1000000000000000000000.000000
023 | 10000000000000000000000.000000
024 | 99999999999999990000000.000000
025 | 1000000000000000000000000.000000
026 | 10000000000000000000000000.000000
027 | 100000000000000000000000000.000000
028 | 1000000000000000000000000000.000000
029 | 10000000000000000000000000000.000000
030 | 100000000000000010000000000000.000000
031 | 1000000000000000000000000000000.000000
032 | 10000000000000000000000000000000.000000
033 | 100000000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

Comment: doubles and floats are not precise, use BigDecimal instead

Comment: OK thanks I will try to use it.

Comment: Do you know how [floating point types work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)?

Comment: @biziclop I have never used big numbers in previously and sadly was not a ware of this issue, I thought I was doing something wrong, thanks every body for productive input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a "stupid problem"; it is one of the core problems of computer science ... dealing with the fact that correct representation of numbers is a non-trivial task.

You might want to start reading [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) for example.

Anybody who is "programming" should understand what this actually means; and how it affects your application/solution.

Comment: Sad I was not a ware of that this is first item I am trying to work with big numbers. thank you

Comment: I do only agree with you. that is my fault.

Comment: @maytham Please don't talk about "fault". We are all learning something new every day. Try to stay curious; anything else isn't important.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused because of convertion from double-precision floating-point format to decimal format. Just like there are periodic numbers in decimals, there are numbers which are periodic in binary but arent in decimal.

Those cases are periodic in binary.

Answer (score 3):

A Java floating point `double` is **always** an IEEE754 64 bit floating point type.

Method 1.

A floating point double **can** represent integers accurately up to the 53rd power of 2. So inaccuracies will creep in once you exceed 9,007,199,254,740,992. (It's a common misconception that floating points always introduce inaccuracy: in your particular case the calculation will be exact for the first few iterations of your loop).

Method 2.

`Math.pow(x, y)` is implemented as exp(y log x) if the two arguments are floating point. That will introduce numerical precision issues, due to a floating point double being only accurate to about 15 significant figures.

Comment: Thank you @bathsheba I will look at my code and correct it.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to Java specification.

In Java, **Integer** uses 32 bits to represent its value. **FLOAT** uses a 24 bit mantissa, so integers greater than 2^23 will have their least significant bits truncated. For example 33554435 (or 0x200003) will be truncated to around 33554432 +/- 4. **DOUBLE** uses a 53 bit mantissa, so will be able to represent a 32bit integer without lost of data.

Check [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-math2/index.html) that explains everything in a very simple way.

Comment: 23 bit mantissa actually since 1 is also used for positive or negative unless its unsigned which will be in fact 24

Comment: True, forgot that part! The answer still holds.